# Make two specific values in one SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem with my query hope you guys can help me,
Table:

```
 ID | Value
 1  |   F
 2  |   V
 2  |   F
 3  |   V
 4  |   F
 4  |   V
```

And i want my query to return P when an ID has both F and V,

```
ID | Value
1  |   F
2  |   P
3  |   V
4  |   P
```

I tried with a CASE

```
WHEN VALUE ='F' AND VALUE ='V' THEN 'P'
                  ELSE VALUE END
```

But it didn't worked.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add (5, F), (5, V) and (5, F)? I understand you want a (5, P) row, but do you also want to keep one (5, F) row?

Comment: It would only add (5,F) and (5,V) no duplicates, if it has both F and V i want to return P so it only keeps (5,P) row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the grouping clause and then handle the scenario in case

```
    SELECT  id, 
        CASE WHEN MIN(ds._value) = 'F' AND MAX(ds._value) = 'V' THEN  'P' ELSE MIN(ds._value) END AS _value
FROM    (
            --making the data set 
            SELECT  '1' AS id,'F' AS _value UNION SELECT    '2','V' UNION 
            SELECT  '2','F' UNION SELECT    '3','V' UNION SELECT    '4','F' UNION SELECT    '4','V'

        ) ds

        GROUP BY id
```

[image: See the image for sample]

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and some conditional logic:

```
select id,
       (case when min(value) = 'F' and max(value) = 'V' then 'P'
             else min(value)
        end) as value
from t
group by id;
```

This assumes that the only values are `'F'` and `'V'`, as in your example.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this ?

```
select Distinct f.id,
CASE WHEN ft.value IS NULL THEN f.value ELSE 'P' END
from TableName f
left join TableName ft on f.id = ft.id AND f.value <> ft.value 
Order by f.Id
```